# Replace zeros with last value different from zero

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
print(inventory_df)

      dt_op  Prod_1  Prod_2  Prod_n
1  10/09/18       5      50       2
2  11/09/18       4       0       0
3  12/09/18       2       0       0
4  13/09/18       0       0       0
5  14/09/18       4      30       1
```

I would like to change the values equal to zero, with the last value != from zero, in each columns, as:

```
print(final_inventory_df)

      dt_op  Prod_1  Prod_2  Prod_n
1  10/09/18       5      50       2
2  11/09/18       4      50       2
3  12/09/18       2      50       2
4  13/09/18       2      50       2
5  14/09/18       4      30       1
```

How could I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Idea is replace `0` to NaNs by [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) and then forward filling them by previous non missing values:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['dt_op'])
df[cols] = df[cols].mask(df[cols] == 0).ffill().astype(int)
```

Similar solution with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df[cols] = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df[cols] == 0, np.nan, df[cols]), 
                        index=df.index, 
                        columns=cols).ffill().astype(int)


print (df)
      dt_op  Prod_1  Prod_2  Prod_n
1  10/09/18       5      50       2
2  11/09/18       4      50       2
3  12/09/18       2      50       2
4  13/09/18       2      50       2
5  14/09/18       4      30       1
```

Solution for fun - convert to integer all columns without `dt_op`:

```
d = dict.fromkeys(df.columns.difference(['dt_op']), 'int')
df = df.mask(df == 0).ffill().astype(d)
```

Comment: What if it reports: ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer? @jezrael

Comment: @AlessandroCeccarelli - It means there is some `NaN` value, so only remove `.astype(int)`

Comment: @AlessandroCeccarelli - Because `NaN` is `float` type and cannot be casted to integers, so raise error

Comment: There are not missing values though; I think that it imported the dataset as float (in Spyder the cells are grey when inspecting it). But with .astype(int) I was not able to convert it, how could I do that?

Comment: @AlessandroCeccarelli - Is possible test it ? `print (df[cols].isnull().values.sum())` ?

Comment: @AlessandroCeccarelli - I think I know what is problem. In data is first row in some column filled by `0`, so after my solution stay `NaN`.

Comment: @AlessandroCeccarelli - oops, solution is  `df[cols] = df[cols].mask(df[cols] == 0).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)`

Comment: @AlessandroCeccarelli - Thanks, glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it suits you! :)

Answer (score 2):

Just another option:

```
df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:].replace(0, np.nan).ffill().astype(int)
```